# How to match regex to any combination of characters and some symbols except two dashes in a row between '% and %'

Tags: java, regex

I want to match the following string:

```
'% Wal-Mart's %'
```

Without matching

```
'% Wal--Mart's %'
```

Or any other string that includes two dashes in between '% and %'.

Currently my regex looks like this:

```
(?<='%)[ \w',&+-]*(?=%')
```

But this allows strings with two dashes through.

How do I match strings that include some combination of characters and symbols (including a single dash) without matching the strings with two dashes in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of repeating the character set, you can repeat a *group* that includes first a negative lookahead for two dashes, followed by the original character set:

```
(?<='%)(?:(?!--)[ \w',&+-])*(?=%')
```

https://regex101.com/r/zDZJsy/1

Comment: I'm not sure this matches the entire string, and the look arounds seem to be somewhat useless perhaps... `'%(?:(?!--)[ \w',&+-])*%'` would probably do the job with far less steps.

Comment: From OP's regex, I'm pretty sure he doesn't want to match the `%'` delimiters, otherwise he wouldn't have used the lookarounds?

Comment: No idea actually, although what you say makes some sense. They show the entire string in the question though, so who knows.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, yes I want to match things in **between** the `'%` and `%'`.
This seems to work! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative lookahead to assert that what you allow to match is not followed by a double dash:

`(?<='%)(?![ \w',&+-]*--)[ \w',&+-]*(?=%')`

In Java

`String regex = "(?<='%)(?![ \\w',&+-]*--)[ \\w',&+-]*(?=%')";`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JGHpCy/1)

That would match

- `(?<='%)` Positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that would assert that what precedes is `%'`
- `(?!` Negative lookahead that assert that what follows is not

  - `[ \w',&+-]*--` Match any character from the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[ \w',&+-]` repeated zero or more times followed by `--`
- `)` Close negative lookahead
- `[ \w',&+-]*` Match a character from the character class zero or more times
- `(?=%')` Positive lookahead that asserts what follows is `%'`

[Java Demo](http://rextester.com/RPPZE65593)